# How to draw 2D & 3D stuffs in OpenGL together?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, opengl, 3d, 2d

How to draw 2D & 3D stuffs in OpenGL together? If possible, please show me some C++ code.
Please show both how to draw behind & in front of 3D objects.

Comment: I've tried gluPerspective to draw things as 3D, then use glOrtho to draw things in 2D, but then 3D stuffs seem to overlay all my 2D drawings, and thus make these 2D things blinking!!!

Comment: Please provide your existing code, we need to see what you've tried, so that we can help you further.

Comment: tks Neil, i've found out why, coz i forgot to call glLoadIdentity

Answer (score 6, accepted):

About that way:

```
void render_perspective_scene(void);

void render_ortho_scene(void);

void render_HUD();

void display()
{
    float const aspect = (float)win_width/(float)win_height;

    glViewport(0,0,win_width,win_height);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glFrustum(-aspect*near/lens, aspect*near/lens, -near/lens, near/lens, near, far);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_perspective_scene();

    // just clear the depth buffer, so that everything that's
    // drawn next will overlay the previously rendered scene.
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-aspect*scale, aspect*scale, -scale, scale, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_ortho_scene();

    // Same for the HUD, only that we render
    // that one in pixel coordinates.
    glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, win_width, 0, win_height, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
    render_HUD();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You are on the right track but you must also disable depth testing when drawing your 2d-graphics: `glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);`

Otherwise it might become hidden by your 3d-graphics.

Comment: diable depth test seems to have meaning only when we draw something behind the 3D scene?